# Mails bounce due to Google IPv6 standards

Tags: php, smtp

I am using the `mail()` function in PHP in order to send mails using SMTP and
i recently noticed that i am not getting a lot of the mails i suppose to get.

A quick view at /var/log/maillog in my server have shown that a lot of the emails are getting bounced with the message:
"Our system has detected that this message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding records and authentication. Please review https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ipv6_authentication_error for more information"

Is there a standard mailing process i should follow to satisfy Google?

this is an example of one of the mails that i fail to get **most** of the times:

```
mail('my_email_goes_here', 'some title', 'my HTML message, including HTML tags such as <ul> and <li>',
                    'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n');
```

For the record, some of the emails are getting sent, but the majority bounce, so maybe it's not the structure of the mail itself but the content?

Answer (score 0):

A few month ago, i had the same problem. The Response from google didnt say much, it only means: "there is anything wrong, find out yourself whats the problem". 
You have to check the google guidelines and see if you meet them. My problem was that i didnt had a reserve DNS entry for my mail server. Google pings the ip of the sedning server and check if the reserve entry returns the correct domain. If its not the case, this error can occur. But in your case it could be another problem to.